# Install GRUB fails when installing ubuntu on a disk configured with RAID 10

Tags: 16.04, system-installation, raid

`Grub -install/dev/sda`fails to execute when installing ubuntu 16.04 LTS on a disk with 4*6TB HDDs configured with RAID 10.
The configuration of the disk is as follows.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ lsblk -o NAME,SIZE,FSTYPE
NAME                  SIZE FSTYPE
sda                   5.5T 
├─sda1                487M linux_raid_member
│ └─md0               972M ext4
├─sda2                954M swap
├─sda3               74.5G linux_raid_member
│ └─md1             148.9G LVM2_member
│   ├─system-rootfs    28G ext4
│   ├─system-tmp      9.3G ext4
│   └─system-varlog   9.3G ext4
└─sda4                5.4T linux_raid_member
  └─md2              10.8T LVM2_member
sdb                   5.5T 
├─sdb1                487M linux_raid_member
│ └─md0               972M ext4
├─sdb2                954M swap
├─sdb3               74.5G linux_raid_member
│ └─md1             148.9G LVM2_member
│   ├─system-rootfs    28G ext4
│   ├─system-tmp      9.3G ext4
│   └─system-varlog   9.3G ext4
└─sdb4                5.4T linux_raid_member
  └─md2              10.8T LVM2_member
sdc                   5.5T 
├─sdc1                487M linux_raid_member
│ └─md0               972M ext4
├─sdc2                954M swap
├─sdc3               74.5G linux_raid_member
│ └─md1             148.9G LVM2_member
│   ├─system-rootfs    28G ext4
│   ├─system-tmp      9.3G ext4
│   └─system-varlog   9.3G ext4
└─sdc4                5.4T linux_raid_member
  └─md2              10.8T LVM2_member
sdd                   5.5T 
├─sdd1                487M linux_raid_member
│ └─md0               972M ext4
├─sdd2                954M swap
├─sdd3               74.5G linux_raid_member
│ └─md1             148.9G LVM2_member
│   ├─system-rootfs    28G ext4
│   ├─system-tmp      9.3G ext4
│   └─system-varlog   9.3G ext4
└─sdd4                5.4T linux_raid_member
  └─md2              10.8T LVM2_member
```

The partition is configured with raid10 md0 as / boot, and the boot loader installation is specified there.
USB is used for installation media.
I would like to tell you about the solution.